# Re-defined method with a yield throws no block given

Tags: ruby, exception, yield

Can someone explain why the last yielder throws a no block given?

```
class Foo
  def yielder
    yield "hello"
  end
end

class Mod

  def initialize
    @@foo = Foo.new
  end

  def self.foo
    @@foo
  end

end

worker = Mod.new

Mod.foo.yielder do |hello|
  puts hello
end

Mod.foo.class.send(:define_method,:yielder) do
   yield "new hello"
end

Mod.foo.yielder do |hello|
  puts hello
end
```

Gives:

> hello
>       test.rb:27:in `block in ': no block given (yield) (LocalJumpError)
>           from test.rb:30:in `'

Comment: It's something to do with `define_method`'s use of `instance_eval`, because if you do it the old-fashioned way with a `class_eval` and a string it works fine, while `instance_eval` gives the same error. Still not seeing it, though :/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A short introduction:

You don't need the Mod-instance, if you define @@foo outside `initialize`.

You don't need the Mod class to get the problem:

```
class Foo
  def yielder
    p 2
    yield "hello"
  end
end
foo = Foo.new

foo.yielder do |hello|
  puts hello
end

foo.class.send(:define_method,:yielder) do
  p 1
   yield "new hello"
end

foo.yielder do |hello|
  puts hello
end
```

You may shorten your example again:

```
class Foo
end
foo = Foo.new

foo.class.send(:define_method,:yielder) do
   yield "new hello"
end

foo.yielder do |hello|
  puts hello
end
```

This is the same as:

```
class Foo
  define_method(:yielder) do
    yield "new hello"
  end
end

foo = Foo.new
foo.yielder do |hello|
  puts hello
end
```

End of Introduction.

And now, I'm not sure if I understood correct what you want (and if I understand ruby correct ;) )
`define_method` accepts a block and use it as method body.
If the new method should receive a block on its own, you must define it in the interface of the definition and call it:

```
class Foo
  define_method(:yielder) do | &prc |
    prc.call("new hello")
  end
end

foo = Foo.new
foo.yielder do |hello|
  puts hello
end
```

Or the same logic in your example:

```
class Foo
  def yielder
    yield "hello"
  end
end

class Mod

  def initialize
    @@foo = Foo.new
  end

  def self.foo
    @@foo
  end

end

worker = Mod.new

Mod.foo.yielder do |hello|
  puts hello
end

Mod.foo.class.send(:define_method,:yielder) do | &prc |
   prc.call "new hello"
end

Mod.foo.yielder do |hello|
  puts hello
end
```

To make the code more robust, I would recommend some checks with `block_given?`.

Comment: It boils down to that sending `define_method` doesn't allow the same implicit block method signature.

Comment: Real world use requires the way it fails some times. Hence this question, but thank you very much for a well elaborated answer.

Comment: Oh, and it also mess up for rspec this one, I bet this case is interesting for the rspec maintainser, I will file this as a issue there with your fine example. I have also filed a issue on ruby itself with a link here.

Comment: Link to issues:
https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/5857
https://github.com/dchelimsky/rspec/issues/48

Comment: This originated as a respec issue that is now solved thank you!

    Mod.foo.should_receive(:some_methhod).once do |&prc|
      prc.call "whatever"
    end